# Can't send DM to people other than me

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I try to DM myself or using `message.author` with the bot it works just fine, but when I try to DM someone else from a server, using their ID, it just returns `discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: User "ID" not found`.I tried with 2 accounts on the same machine and when I was using only one of the accounts it didn't work, but when I logged in to the second one (while still having my main opened) it worked just fine. Here is what I'm using:

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, victim: discord.User, *, message=None):
        user = await bot.fetch_user("ID")
        await user.send("message")
```

In addition, when I'm DMing myself(or `message.author`) I can't have it working while I have an event set up for reading messages. When I comment it out, the DM command works again.

```
@bot.event
   async def on_message(message):
     print(message.author.name + " : " + message.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue is with the `ID` you placed it as a string instead it should be `victim.id`. Also you didn't use the `message` variable

Use it like this
`{prefix} dm @user Hello this is a test`

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, victim: discord.Member, *, message: str = None):
    if message:
        await victim.send(message)
    else:
        await victim.send("No message context")
```

Comment: What should be entered in the victim?

Comment: @H3xcOokie Please check above i edited the code a bit and made an example.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
await ctx.message.author.send("Hello.")
```

Comment: I already said in the post, that this works without any trouble.